# Systemd status says daemon active (running), but daemon isn't executing and creates duplicate processes

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, fork, raspbian, systemd

Below is the code for the daemon (in C).

```
    int main(void) {
    
    /* Our process ID and Session ID */
    pid_t pid2;
    
    /* The Big Loop */
    while (1) {
        time_t now;
        time(&now);
        struct tm *local = localtime(&now);
        int hour = local->tm_hour;
        int min = local->tm_min;
        int earliest_time = 0; //8AM earliest a workout will be developed
        int latest_time = 24; //5PM latest a workout will be developed
        int min_interval = 20; //minimum interval of a workout
        int max_interval = 30; //maximum interval of a workout

        //If it's in between these hours of the day...
        if (hour >= earliest_time && hour < latest_time){

            int rand_interval = (rand() % (max_interval + 1 - min_interval)) + min_interval;

            pid2 = fork();
            if (pid2 == 0){
                execlp("./workout_SMS.py","./workout_SMS.py",NULL);
            }
            
            waitpid(pid2,0,0);
            //kill(pid2,SIGTERM);
            sleep(rand_interval);
        }

        else{
        sleep(60); /* wait 30 seconds */
        }
    }
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

}

I want this daemon to start at boot using Systemd. In accordance with the Systemd manual and other online sources, I've configured a daemon.service file as shown below.

```
[Unit]
Description=workout-daemon startup service
[Service]
User=pi
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Below is the Systemd status of the daemon. As shown, the status says that it's "active (running)" and over time, continues to create new duplicate processes. The desired behavior is that it only runs one process and not create duplicates.

```
● workout.service - workout-daemon startup service file for text message workouts
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/workout.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-12-29 03:15:35 PST; 1min 41s ago
 Main PID: 22363 (workout-daemon)
    Tasks: 5 (limit: 881)
   CGroup: /system.slice/workout.service
           ├─22363 /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
           ├─22364 /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
           ├─22409 /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
           ├─22493 /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
           └─22525 /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon
```

The expected operation is that the python script sends a text message to my phone at specific intervals. The daemon will function as expected when run directly from the working directory, but it doesn't function as expected when I use "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" -> "sudo systemctl enable workout.service" -> "sudo systemctl start workout.service".

Is there anything I'm missing in my configuration of Systemd?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't function as expected"? What should it do and what is it actually doing? Have you tried making the self `fork` an option (e.g. if the program is given a `-f`). Then, have `systemd` control it normally (i.e. under `systemd`, the program does _not_ `fork`). [AFAICT] Most services do _not_ do `Type=forking`

Comment: I've edited the daemon C code in the original question to include the code in the while(1) loop. I've removed the fork() in the int main portion of the function and changed the type to Type=simple in the .service config file. Now the Systemd status says it's inactive (dead) and 'code'workout.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=15/TERM'code'

Comment: `systemd` is detecting and complaining about the `kill(pid2,SIGTERM);` you're doing. There's _no_ need because after the `waitpid`, `pid2` is _gone_. So, remove the `kill`. Note: A moot point, but my best guess is the _reason_ it complained is that you were _not_ doing: `if (pid2 != 0) kill(pid2,SIGTERM);` so you were doing `kill(0,SIGTERM);` which means: _If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the **calling** process._ Hence, your daemon was killing _itself_

Comment: Removing the kill(pid2,SIGTERM) command now allows the daemon to be active (running), but I think by removing it, every time the wait(1) statement re-occurs, a new instance of /home/pi/python/twilio/workout_SMS/workout-daemon is created and they begin accumulating in the background 1 at a time. And despite being active and creating a new process, my phone is not getting a text messages from any of the processes. Any thoughts on why a new instance of the daemon would be created after every iteration of the wait(1) loop? And why it would ignore the python script entirely?

Comment: You're doing `chdir("/");`. Later, you're doing `execlp("./workout_SMS.py",...);` What would happen if the `execlp` failed (i.e. how to handle? do `printf` and then `exit(9)`)?

Comment: I'd add logging to the daemon so you can see the activity. You can add extra/temporary debug messages.

Comment: @CraigEstey I updated the original question/code to reflect our progress. I removed the 'chdir("/");' early in the debug process, so my update prior to this didn't use 'chdir("/"). I will add debug messages and return with any findings. Thanks for the help